# Is the singular homology of a real algebraic set always finitely generated?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ag.algebraic-geometry, homology

Here is a precise statement of my question:

Let $p\in \mathbb{R}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ be a polynomial, and let $Z(p)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be the set of zeros of $p$.  Must the singular homology $H_i (Z(p); \mathbb{Z})$ ($i\geq 0$) be finitely generated as an abelian group?

Here I really just mean the singular homology groups of this set as a topological space with the Euclidean topology.

It's an old theorem of Whitney that $Z(p)$ has finitely many connected components, so $H_0 (Z(p); \mathbb{Z})$ is finitely generated.  Note that it is possible to triangulate $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $Z(p)$ as a subcomplex, so $H_i (Z(p)) = 0$ for $i>n$.

I'm guessing the answer is well-known (either a theorem or a counterexample), but I couldn't find an answer on Google or MathSciNet...

Answer (score 10):

Proposition 1.13 of these [notes](http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/michel.coste/polyens/RASroot.pdf) by Coste implies (if I've read it correctly) that any semialgebraic set $S$ is homeomorphic to a union $U$ of open simplices in some finite simplicial complex $K$.

Thus $S$ is an open subset of an ENR, hence is an ENR. Its singular cohomology therefore coincides with its Čech cohomology, which is finitely generated. Therefore its singular homology must be finitely generated.

**Edit:** The argument given above is incomplete, since a union of "open" simplices in a simplicial complex is not necessarily open (an easy mistake to make!). However it is easy to see that $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is an ENR by other means (in particular, it is locally compact and locally contractible).

Comment: Ah, the trick I was missing is that any semialgebraic set is equivalent to a bounded one, by the trick explained just prior to Proposition 1.13.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dan Ramras If you were only concerned with possible noncompactness of $M=Z(p)$ that is easy to deal with directly. For any $v\in \mathbb R^n$ look at $f_v(x)=|x-v|^2$. If $M$ is smooth then $f_v$ is a Morse function on $M$ for most $v\in \mathbb R^n$ (so long as $v$ is not a focal point of $M$). For any such $v$ the set of critical points of $f_v$ on $M$ is real algebraic and discrete and hence finite (e.g. by the Theorem of Whitney you mention). Therefore $M$ deformation retracts onto its intersection with the closed ball $\bar B(v,R)$ for some finite $R$.

Comment: Vitali, that's a nice observation.  I am specifically interested in the case of singular algebraic sets, however.

Comment: @Dan Ramras the singular case follows from above because any algebraic set has finitely many smooth strata and you can choose $f_v$ that works for all of them. this easily yields a smooth gradient like vector field for $f_v$ tangent to $M$ on $M$  and without critical points outside a large ball.

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be proved in Chapter 9 of Bochnak/Coste/Roy "Real Algebraic Geometry". In Chapter 11 they prove bounds on the Betti numbers (if you care about $\mathbb{Q}$ coefficients).